# Google Maps API returns zoomed out repeated view of the globe - possible incorrect coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a project where I am showing 8,000+ lat/long coordinates on a Google Map. Works great.

[image]

Today I uploaded another 3,000+, and now the Google Map shows a world view of the globe, repeated horizontally, with a lot of gray space on top.

[image]

I've looked through the 3,000+ entries, and do not see any where alpha characters, missing lat/long values, etc - something obvious.

The only thing that I can think of is that a lat/long entry is incorrect, and thus the Google Map zoom breaks? Reviewing questions on SO show hacks such as setting `minZoom` or `zoom` levels - but I feel that isn't the right path to go across to solve this, since it was working before and something is happening with my new records. I've checked that no pins are on the map outside USA which may cause the entire world view to show.

I'm reaching out to the community to see if anyone smarter than me has a tip or suggestion to help edge case occurrences like this, and/or if my assumption of a wrong lat/long is breaking the Map?

Comment: Probably a data problem with one of the new points.  Looks like you have a latitude that is > 90 degrees, but can only guess.

Comment: yes i think you hit it right on the head @geocodezip. the latest sheet i uploaded has lat/long without dots - i.e., 64854713 instead of 64.854713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your lat/long is incorrect. Instead of Google Maps API failing and alerting, it just breaks the map. I'd advise you to run your locations to confirm decimals exists per each record.